# Routes parameter transformation throws on parsing failure String -> Int

Tags: scala, playframework

Router config using Play [parameter transformation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#parameter-types):

`GET   /search   controllers.Search.query(page: Option[Int])`

while `search?page=123` works as expected, visiting `search?page=asd` throws

We're using our own wrappers to contain failures `Try { param.toInt }.toOption` but is there another way to cleanly contain parse exceptions in `routes` configuration or `Action` block?

Also: does anyone see parameter transformation is represented in the [Play source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/d6c2673d91d85fd37de424951ee5ad9f4f4cce98/framework/src/play/src/main/scala)?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Option[Int]` to `Option[String]`

inside the action

```
def search(param: Option[String]) = Action { req =>
  val page = param.flatMap { Try { _.toInt }.toOption }
  doSomething(page).map { Ok(_) }
}
```

*if you use `Option[Int]` parsing of query params happens at play routes level and play will handle the exception for you and you will not have control on it. So use `Option[String]` and parse `String` in the `Action` to anything you would like to see*

use `withParamAction` to avoid duplicate code

```
def withParamAction(f: Option[Int] => Request[AnyContent] => Result)(paramName: String = "page"):Result = Action { req =>
  f(req.getQueryString(paramName).flatMap { Try { _.toInt }.toOption })(req)
}
```

*extending or writing a custom `int bindable` should be what is required in your situation `customIntBinder`*

If you want to parse Query string to Complex objects use `QueryStringBindle`in play. Here is the example code from play docs.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders#QueryStringBindable

Comment: thanks @pamu that's what we are currently doing. I'm hoping to avoid that boilerplate on each action block. Ideally Int parse failures in play would evaluate to an empty option.

Comment: thanks for giving this a go -- that's a cool idea but I'd like a more generic solution to handle N params for any primitive type. i think I may play with overiding the implicit Parsers https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9f26118a52b8628fe911e6d5fe878d72fe0878b4/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Binders.scala#L62  thoughts?

Comment: @tgk https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders#QueryStringBindable

Comment: @tgk extending or writing a custom int bindable should be what is required in your situation `customIntBinder`